# Prokhorov metric vs. total variation norm

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, metric-spaces

Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space and let $\mathcal P(S)$ denote the space of Borel probability measures on $S$ endowed with the [Prokhorov metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric) $\pi:\mathcal P(S)\times \mathcal P(S)\to \mathbb R_+$ given by
$$
  \pi(P,Q):=\inf\{\varepsilon\geq 0:P(F)\leq Q(F^\varepsilon)+\varepsilon \text{ for all closed } F\subset S\}
$$
where the $\varepsilon$-inflation of a set is given by  $  F^{\varepsilon} = \{x\in S:d(x,F)<\varepsilon\}.$

Another useful metric on $\mathcal P(S)$ is induced by the total variation norm, i.e. 
$$
  \rho(P,Q):=\sup\limits_{A\in \mathfrak B(S)}|P(A) - Q(A)|
$$
where $\mathfrak B(S)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $(S,d)$. I wonder if there are any interesting relations between these two metrics, $\pi$ and $\rho$. In particular, I know that convergence in $\rho$ implies the weak convergence and hence if $S$ is separable than it implies the convergence in $\pi$.

I wonder, however, if under some additional assumptions it is possible to derive some non-trivial bounds on $\rho$ if I know upper bounds on $\pi$. Or at least, if it is possible to upper-bound $|P(F) - Q(F)|$ for closed $F$ using $\pi$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On metric spaces, the Prokhorov metric can always be bounded by the total variation metric. If $S$ is finite, you can bound the total variation metric by the Prokhorov metric via the Wasserstein metric.

More metrics and their relations (including the ones above) are nicely summariced in [Gibbs A.L. and Su F.E., *On Choosing and Bounding Probability Metrics*,  International Statistical Review 70 (2002), pp. 419-435](http://www.math.hmc.edu/~su/papers.dir/metrics.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a nice reference! Just one comment, did you mean that if $S$ is finite than Prokhorov metric can be bounded by the TV one via the Wasserstein metric?

Comment: Actually, the first statement was incorrect ($\pi\leq \rho$, but $\rho \leq c \pi$ only for finite $S$); fixed now. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I also misread the direction of the arrows, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Generally, knowing things about $\pi$ cannot tell you much about $\rho$; weak convergence is much easier to achieve than total variation convergence.

For example, if $S$ is any non-discrete space, $x$ is a limit point, and $x_n \to x$ is a sequence with $x_n \ne x$ for all $n$, then the point masses $\delta_{x_n}$ satisfy $\pi(\delta_{x_n}, \delta_x) \to 0$.  (Indeed, $\pi(\delta_{x_n}, \delta_x) = d(x_n, x)$.)  But we have $\rho(\delta_{x_n}, \delta_x) = 1$ for every $n$.

Comment: Thanks, Nate - I guess it answers also my point about closed sets. Also, here I think $\rho(\delta_{x_n},\delta_x) = 1$ as I defined it as a half-total variation (often done for probability measures)

Comment: @S.D.: You're right, it should be 1.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple inequality relating the Prohorov metric $\pi$ and the total variation norm $\|\;\|_{TV}$for probability measures:
Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures on a metric space $(S,d)$. For any Borel set $A\subset S$,

\begin{aligned}
\mu(A)&=\mu(A)-\nu(A)+\nu(A)\leq \|\mu-\nu\|_{TV}+\nu(A) \\
&\leq \|\mu-\nu\|_{TV} + \nu\big(A^{\|\mu-\nu\|_{TV}}\big)
\end{aligned}
whence we obtained that
$$\pi(\mu,\nu)\leq\|\mu-\nu\|_{TV}
$$

---

Another relevant metric is the Kantorovih-Rubinstein metric
$$\beta(\mu,\nu)=\sup\left\{\Big|\int f(d\mu-d\nu)\Big|: f\in\operatorname{Lip}_1\right\}
$$
where $\operatorname{Lip}_1$ is the space of Lipschitz functions on $S$ such that $\|f\|_{BL}=\|f\|_\infty+\|f\|_L\leq1$
where $\|f\|_L=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d(x,y)}$. It is a well know fact that $\beta$ and $\pi$ produce the same topology on the space of probability measures, namely the weak topology $\sigma(\mathcal{M}(S),\mathcal{C}_b(S))$ restricted to $\mathcal{M}^+_1(S)$ the space of probabilities on $(S,d)$. The following is also well known:
\begin{aligned}
\frac12\beta(\mu,\nu)&\leq \pi(\mu,\nu)\leq\Big(\frac32\beta(\mu,\nu)\Big)^{1/2}\\
\beta(\mu,\nu)&\leq \|\mu-\nu\|_{TV}
\end{aligned}

Dudley's book Real Analysis and Probability chapter 11  is a good reference.