# Total variation norm against uniform metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let's consider probability functions $G(\mathbf{x}, a)$ and $F(\mathbf{x}, a)$  of 2 continuous random vectors.  $a$ is a parameter. Let the convergence $$\sup_{\mathbf{x}}|G(\mathbf{x},a)-F(\mathbf{x}, a)|\stackrel{a \to 0}\rightarrow 0$$ hold (convergence w.r.t. uniform metric holds). Is it true that the convergence (with $a\to 0$) of corresponding probabilty measures w.r.t. total variation norm holds too?

The file from the answer to the question [Prokhorov metric vs. total variation norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246412/prokhorov-metric-vs-total-variation-norm) was great but unfortunately not enough

Could you help to understand please? Thanks in advance